# Force Chrome to use subpixel rendering for floats

Tags: css, image-resizing

I am trying to have 8 images floated by each other with

```
width: 25%; 
float: left;
```

Here is a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/y06z0em1/

If you resize the section that the images are in, you will see that there are times when it breaks because some of the images are off by a fraction of a pixel. Could I ever change make it so that every pixel always rounds up or down?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browsers round fractional pixels automatically and this is browser specific, some round it up, some down; There is no way to force it to do one or the other with CSS.

A solution could be to work with LESS, there are functions for that (`ceil`, `floor`).

But if you need a solution with CSS I would just suggest define the width as `calc(100% - 0.5px)` / `calc(100% -1px)` or `99.9%`. That's just not perfect, but a solution. You can adjust it as you like and as it works for you.

**But** I'm not sure your problem comes from that.
Take a look at the following fiddle and tell me if it solves your problem. Instead of floating I use a layout based on `display:inline-block` here, and it seems like there is not such a problem.
https://jsfiddle.net/a693yj52/

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! How would I remove the margins/spaces around it if I can't do the </tag><tag> hack? Right now I'm just using negative margins + calc to add 1px to the width. Is there anything else you suggest?

Comment: You also can use comments ``</tag><!-- --><tag>`` between the tags. It's what I usually do.
Other possibilities are listed here: https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using Flexbox here.

It'd look something like this:

```
.container {
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container > * {
   flex-basis: 25%;
   height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Although your solution would be more elegant, I used ScientiaEtVeritas for more browser support. Thanks for your time and help!

Comment: No problem, just keep in mind that `calc` can have some performance drawbacks that are very noticeable on lower-power devices.